# C# Oracle LINQ Query reusing the context for a second query on a given view returns result from first query

Tags: c#, oracle, linq

There seems to be a bug in Oracle LINQ (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework version="12.1.2400) in that reusing a context (I don't reuse contexts: this was code I inherited) means that if a query is performed on view V_MYVIEW then a second query on the same view returns the result from the first time the query was executed. The code I inherited uses Unity to inject the context in a lifecycle of web-thread.

I have fixed this by using a "using (var context = new MyContext)" statement rather than the injected context. Just curious if anyone else has come across this behaviour with Oracle LINQ, and an alternative solution.

original code:

```
public async Task<List<Thing>> GetThings(string search1)
        {
            var list = injectedContext.V_MYVIEW
                .Where(p=>p.SEARCH1 == search1)
                .Select(p => new ThingModel
                {
                    Thing1 = p.THING1,
                }).ToListAsync();
            return list;        
        }
```

new code:

```
public async Task<List<Thing>> GetThings(string search1)
        {
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                var list = await context.V_MYVIEW
                    .Where(p=>p.SEARCH1 == search1)
                    .Select(p => new ThingModel
                    {
                        Thing1 = p.THING1,
                    }).ToListAsync();
                return list;
            }
        }
```

I never reuse contexts since the using statement is so neat, and disposes it neatly (therefore releasing resources for GC), and contexts are very cheap to create. (and also it's the recommended practice for all these reasons).
Nevertheless, this has to be a bug in Oracle LINQ doesn't it?

Comment: reusing how? do you mean if you call GetThings("q1") and GetThings("q2") return same results ?

Comment: Yes. That's what happens with the same context "q2" is actually returning the results from the earlier query "q1". With the "using" clause though, and a disposed context, all seems ok. There are two more recent versions of the EF Oracle driver, but release notes do not indicate that this bug has been identified and fixed.